# How to convert JSON-LD to dart object

Tags: flutter, dart, json-ld, api-platform.com

I'm usign Symfony API Platform and Flutter for web project. The Api returns JSON-LD format like this :

[image]

but I got this error:

[image]

For the flutter projcet, I have followed the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data :

**Class Book:**

```
class Book {
final int id;
final String isbn;
final String title;

  Book({this.id, this.isbn, this.title});

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      isbn: json['isbn'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );
  }

}
```

This is **book_http_service.dart :**

```
class BookHttpService {
  Future<Book> listBooks() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/books');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Book.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load books');
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the interface where to display books (**book_list.dart**)

```
class _BookState extends State<BookList> {
  final BookHttpService bookHttpService = BookHttpService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<Book>(
        future: bookHttpService.listBooks(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.title);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error.toString()}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can see `Book` class in full code 
Step 1: Assume your json string look like this

```
 String jsonString = '''
    {
 "@context": "api/contexts/Book",
 "@id":"api/books",
 "@type":"hydra:Collection",
 "hydra:member":[
 {
   "@id": "api/books/2",
   "@type": "Book",
   "id":2,
   "isbn":"8545",
   "title":"test body",
   "author":"abc",
   "pubLicationDate":"2020-01-14T16:29:16+01:00",
   "active":false,
   "owner":null
 },
 {
   "@id": "api/books/2",
   "@type": "Book",
   "id":1,
   "isbn":"1234",
   "title":"test body 2",
   "author":"def",
   "pubLicationDate":"2020-01-14T16:29:16+01:00",
   "active":false,
   "owner":null
 }
 ]
}
    ''';
```

Step 2: parse with `bookFromJson(response.body);` 
Step 3: display data with `ListView`

```
FutureBuilder<Book>(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.hydraMember.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                          child:
                              Text('${snapshot.data.hydraMember[index].title}'))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Book bookFromJson(String str) => Book.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String bookToJson(Book data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Book {
  String context;
  String id;
  String type;
  List<HydraMember> hydraMember;

  Book({
    this.context,
    this.id,
    this.type,
    this.hydraMember,
  });

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Book(
        context: json["@context"],
        id: json["@id"],
        type: json["@type"],
        hydraMember: List<HydraMember>.from(
            json["hydra:member"].map((x) => HydraMember.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "@context": context,
        "@id": id,
        "@type": type,
        "hydra:member": List<dynamic>.from(hydraMember.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class HydraMember {
  String id;
  String type;
  int hydraMemberId;
  String isbn;
  String title;
  String author;
  DateTime pubLicationDate;
  bool active;
  dynamic owner;

  HydraMember({
    this.id,
    this.type,
    this.hydraMemberId,
    this.isbn,
    this.title,
    this.author,
    this.pubLicationDate,
    this.active,
    this.owner,
  });

  factory HydraMember.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HydraMember(
        id: json["@id"],
        type: json["@type"],
        hydraMemberId: json["id"],
        isbn: json["isbn"],
        title: json["title"],
        author: json["author"],
        pubLicationDate: DateTime.parse(json["pubLicationDate"]),
        active: json["active"],
        owner: json["owner"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "@id": id,
        "@type": type,
        "id": hydraMemberId,
        "isbn": isbn,
        "title": title,
        "author": author,
        "pubLicationDate": pubLicationDate.toIso8601String(),
        "active": active,
        "owner": owner,
      };
}

class BookHttpService {
  Future<Book> listBooks() async {
    //final response = await http.get('http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/books');
    String jsonString = '''
    {
 "@context": "api/contexts/Book",
 "@id":"api/books",
 "@type":"hydra:Collection",
 "hydra:member":[
 {
   "@id": "api/books/2",
   "@type": "Book",
   "id":2,
   "isbn":"8545",
   "title":"test body",
   "author":"abc",
   "pubLicationDate":"2020-01-14T16:29:16+01:00",
   "active":false,
   "owner":null
 },
 {
   "@id": "api/books/2",
   "@type": "Book",
   "id":1,
   "isbn":"1234",
   "title":"test body 2",
   "author":"def",
   "pubLicationDate":"2020-01-14T16:29:16+01:00",
   "active":false,
   "owner":null
 }
 ]
}
    ''';

    final response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return bookFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load books');
    }
  }
}

class BookList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BookListState createState() => _BookListState();
}

class _BookListState extends State<BookList> {
  Future _future;
  final BookHttpService bookHttpService = BookHttpService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = bookHttpService.listBooks();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<Book>(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.hydraMember.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                          child:
                              Text('${snapshot.data.hydraMember[index].title}')),
                    );
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error.toString()}");
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BookList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you I have tested it and works good, but isn't too long ? imagine I have 30 classes or more. By the way it works even I remove Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {} in the two classes , can you tell me the utility of them ?

Comment: could you please check my response and tell me  if is it good or not ? thanks

Comment: toJson is can convert back Object to Json String.

Comment: You can just do json.decode and return Map, but Model can help you to do compile check and can help to convert back to Json String if you need to do http post. Project team members can communicate with Model more easy than with a Map.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short script based on exmaples of [Sqlite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite#example), and it works good:

**Class book:**

```
class Book {
  String schemaContext;
  String schemaId;
  String schemaType;
  int id;
  String title;

  Book({
    this.schemaContext,
    this.schemaId,
    this.schemaType,
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });

  factory Book.fromJson(schema, Map<String, dynamic> json) => Book(
        schemaContext: schema['@context'],
        schemaId: schema['@id'],
        schemaType: schema['@type'],
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
      );

}
```

**BookHttpService:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:book_app/models/book.dart';

class BookHttpService {
  Future<List<Book>> listBooks() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/books');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = json.decode(response.body);
      return List.generate(result['hydra:member'].length, (i) {
        return Book.fromJson(result, result['hydra:member'][i]);
      });
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load books');
    }
  }
}
```

**book_list.dart:**

```
class _BookState extends State<BookList> {
  final BookHttpService bookHttpService = BookHttpService();

  List<Book> books;
  Book book;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List books'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: bookHttpService.listBooks(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            books = snapshot.data;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: books.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                  book = books[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                    child: Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () {},
                        title: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: book.title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 15.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("error");
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```